# How to add data attribute to all images in posts

Tags: images

I want to use his image zoom function on my wordpress site:
[Medium's Image Zoom in vanilla JS](https://github.com/spinningarrow/zoom-vanilla.js)

but I'm not sure how to add

```
data-action="zoom"
```

attribute to all images attached in posts. What function I need to use? Can somebody help me?

Comment: Attached in the post you mean directly to the content of the post?

Comment: Yes, I mean directly to the content.

Comment: you can use jquery like this `jQuery('.class_name').attr('data-action','zoom')`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure which class name to add. I need this to be attached to all posted images.

Comment: You can use class `wp-post-image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options.

You could use the `add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_data_attributes' );`
And after that find the images attached to the post.

Or you can use the `image_send_to_editor` filter more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll read more about both options and try it.

Comment: This is a good hint to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code where you run the post loop after `<?php get_footer(); ?>`

```
    <script>
    jQuery('.wp-post-image').attr('data-action','zoom')
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This work, but I have a problem. Images don't have .wp-post-image class. I inspect an image and class is wp-image-1928 ... so every image have different class. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: did you find any common class? if any common classes are there than use that one instead of `wp-post-image`.